# patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb maven plugin exclude precision and scale from @Column for Double fields

Tags: maven, jaxb, xjc, hyperjaxb

My situation is close to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74480707/jaxb2-basics-annotate-plugin-migration-to-jaxb-3-0-and-jakarta-namespace). I use [patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb maven plugin](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb) to generate entity classes with JPA annotions from xsd schema along with krasa-jaxb-tools plugin, which add validation annotaions.
There are some elements with `type="xs:double"` in my xsd scheme and after classes generation there are some `Double` fields which annotated `@Column` like this:

```
    @Column(name = "SOURCE_RATIO", precision = 20, scale = 10)
    public Double getSourceRatio() {
        return sourceRatio;
    }
```

Then I generate Spring Data repositories with [cmeza20/spring-data-generator](https://github.com/cmeza20/spring-data-generator) and use Spring Data REST dependency.
Besides of all, I want to auto-create my database scheme, so I put that property in my `application.properties` file:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

And when I run my application I get "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: scale has no meaning for floating point numbers". How can I configurate `@Column` annotation to exclude precision and scale for `Double` java type?

I think the [plugin](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb) have no any options to configure this (maybe [Mr.O'Sullivan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3235583/rick-osullivan), plugin developer, can comment on that). But maybe "binding.xjc" may help with this problem. I don't have much experience with setting up the bindings file, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a HyperJAXB customization for `default-single-property` to your XJC binding file, something like this:

**bindings.xjb**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings jaxb:version="3.0"
    xmlns:jaxb="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:hj="http://jvnet.org/hyperjaxb/jpa"
    xmlns:orm="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="hj orm"
>
    ...
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd" node="/xs:schema">

        <hj:persistence>
            <hj:default-single-property type="xs:double">
                <hj:basic>
                    <orm:column />
                </hj:basic>
            </hj:default-single-property>
        </hj:persistence>

    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Indeed, you identified a bug in the [HypeJAXB](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb#readme) plugin. The plugin unmarshals its own [DefaultCustomizations.xml](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb/blob/master/ejb/plugin/src/main/resources/org/jvnet/hyperjaxb/ejb/strategy/customizing/impl/DefaultCustomizations.xml) to configure a `Persistence` object which it uses to customize the generated classes. If you scroll the XML to find the entry for "3.2.5 xsd:double" you will see the origin of the `precision` and `scale` bug. This entry refers to [Section 3.2.5 of XML Schema Part 2: Datatypes Second Edition (2004)](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#double). That section shows that the `precision` and `scale` facets are *not defined* for double (or float).

Thank you for bringing this to my attention. I'll review and correct `DefaultCustomizations.xml` for the next release. If you add an [issue](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb/issues) for this you can keep track of the progress (and remind me to do the review!).

-- Rick

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much! Impoves to bindings.xjb helped. I add [this issue](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb/issues/2) to remind you fix this bug for the next release.