# JAXB 3 with property change support in setter methods

Tags: maven, jaxb, xjc, jakarta-migration

In the past there existed the property-listener-injector plugin for the org.jvnet.jaxb2maven plugin.
One can still find the plugin in maven central repo : org.jvnet.jaxb2-commons:property-listener-injector:1.0 and with google search many forum posts that relate to this.

Now Rick O'Sullivan did a great job and adapted the jaxb-maven.plugin to jakarta namespace and jaxb 3/jaxb 4.
I found his answer to a related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74909223/14565514
Many thanks for that - I tried out and it's working very good.
Although I am asking I you see a possibility to merge it back to the original repo instead of maintaining a fork?

But the real question is that I am missing the property-listener-injector plugin.
To *Rick O'Sullivans* defense it is also not existend anymore on *Alexey Valikov* (aka Highsource) repo - at least I couldn find it in the list of JAXB2 basic plugins here : https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools#jaxb2-basics

Is there a possibility to get jakarta namespace and property change support in setter methods with JAXB 3 (or 4) and maven?
Do I have overseen something?

I tried the approach mentioned a long time ago here
https://www.java-forum.org/thema/propertychangelistener-generieren-mit-jaxb-xjc.124023/
This is from 2011 and understandable not compatible with jaxb 3 or jakarta namespace.

Many other similar forum/blog posts can be found with google search but all are rather out dated.

Any help or hint is appreciated! - Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A new [PropertyListenerPlugin](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb/blob/master/plugins/src/main/java/org/jvnet/basicjaxb/plugin/propertylistener/PropertyListenerPlugin.java) has been added to [HiSrc BasicJAXB](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb/tree/master#hisrc-basicjaxb). It will be included in the next release (no ETA).

Comment: Rick you're awesome!

Many thanks for your answer and the plugin!
I will definitely give it a try.

Comment: The [PropertyListenerPlugin](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb/blob/master/plugins/src/main/java/org/jvnet/basicjaxb/plugin/propertylistener/PropertyListenerPlugin.java) is available in [HiSrc BasicJAXB Release 2.2.0](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb/releases/tag/2.2.0). The plugin can generate either bound and/or constrained (vetoable) `PropertyChangeEvent`s.

Answer (score 0):

I already said in the comment:  I will give it definitely a try.
Since comments are restricted in amount of characters I'll answere here to the answer of Rick.

I found a solution by extending the generated classes and overwrite the setters as suggested here:
[Jaxb 2 user guide](https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/doc/user-guide/ch03.html)
See section about adding behaviours.

This is JAXB 2 but the approach is somewhat general.
The only "problem" is then when the unmarshaller reads in an XML document it will, per default, generate a model consisting only of the generated and not the extended classes. This can be corrected by defining the ObjectFactory and then pass the ObjectFactoryExtended.

```
 unmarshaller.setProperty("org.glassfish.jaxb.core.ObjectFactory", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new ObjectFactoryEx());
```

The concrete property String depends on which JAXB implementation is used.

That introduces another layer into my project but for now that is ok.
If your plugin is released then I will give it a try and try to remove this additional layer if possible.

Out of curiosity - I have a question though: I saw that the original org.jvnet jaxb maven plugins have a lot of forks. I assume due to the lack of JAXB 3/4 support.
Wouldn't it be "better" instead of doeing a fork to support the original repo and go for a merge request there? What are youre reasons for a fork instead of doeing the work in the original repo?